# What is the best way for reducing multiple if statement?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

I have a helper function that builds object with appropriate query properties. I use this object as a body in my promise request. What is the most elegant way for refactoring multiple if statements? Here is a function:

```
 getQueryParams = (query, pagination, sorting) => {
        let queryParam = {}

        if (pagination && pagination.pageNumber) {
            queryParam.page = `${pagination.pageNumber}`
        }
        if (pagination && pagination.rowsOnPage) {
            queryParam.size = `${pagination.rowsOnPage}`
        }
        if (query) {
            const updatedQuery = encodeURIComponent(query)
            queryParam.q = `${updatedQuery}`
        }
        if (sorting) {
            queryParam.sort = `${sorting.isDescending ? '-' : ''}${sorting.name}`
        }
        return service.get(`/my-url/`, queryParam).then(result => {
            return result
        })
    }
```

Comment: only starting two if's are similar and can be reduced by a loop, rest of them have separate logic, so i don't think you can reduce it much

Comment: Teach your service to check empty/undefined/null values, and pass all keys with a default value. ex. `let queryParam = {page: pagination.pageNumber || undefined, ...};`. Some of the default values can be defined in the argument list too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `service` checks its parameters (as it should), you could benefit from the [default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters). Something like this:

```
const getQueryParams = (
  query = '',
  pagination = {pageNumber: 0, rowsOnPage: 0},
  sorting = {isDescending: '', name: ''}
) => {
  const queryParam = {
    page: pagination.pageNumber,
    size: pagination.rowsOnPage,
    q: encodeURIComponent(query),
    sort: `${sorting.isDescending}${sorting.name}`    
  }
  return ...;
};
```

A live example to play with at [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gtbsmjy4/).

Answer (score -2):

This is an idea how it could looks like, but you need to adopt your params before:

```
  const query = new URLSearchParams();
  Object.keys(params).forEach(key => {
    if (params[key]) {
      query.append(key, params[key]);
    }
  });
```